# not able to run springboot web application

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

[here is my project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKZa5.png)

1. main class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java

   ```
           package com.javainuse;

               import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
               import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

               @SpringBootApplication
               public class SpringBootHelloWorldApplication {

                   public static void main(String[] args) {
                       SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
                   }
               }
               [project layout][1]
   ```

   2. mapping TestController.java

      ```
              package com.javainuse.controllers;

              import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
              import org.springframework.ui.Model;
              import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
              import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
              import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

              @Controller
              public class TestController {

                  @RequestMapping("/welcome")
                  public String firstPage(ModelMap map) {

                      return "welcome";
                  }

              }
      ```
   3. welcome.jsp

      ```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
          <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
          <head>
          <title>First Web Application</title>
          </head>
          </html>
      ```

4.application.properties

```
        server.port=8086
        spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
        spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

    5.pom.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
        <artifactId>SpringBootHelloWorld</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>SpringBootHelloWorld</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            </dependency> -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.7</version>
            </dependency>



        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


    </project>

6. error in console after hitting http://localhost:8086/welcome
```

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2017-11-24 23:38:08.290  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication      : Starting SpringBootHelloWorldApplication on NITISH with PID 10028 (C:\Users\sumit\workspace1\SpringBootHelloWorld\target\classes started by sumit in C:\Users\sumit\workspace1\SpringBootHelloWorld)
2017-11-24 23:38:08.291  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-11-24 23:38:08.296  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@53707808: startup date [Fri Nov 24 23:38:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-24 23:38:09.020  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8086 (http)
2017-11-24 23:38:09.022  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-11-24 23:38:09.022  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2017-11-24 23:38:09.033  INFO 10028 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-11-24 23:38:09.034  INFO 10028 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 738 ms
2017-11-24 23:38:09.085  INFO 10028 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-11-24 23:38:09.086  INFO 10028 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-24 23:38:09.086  INFO 10028 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-24 23:38:09.086  INFO 10028 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-24 23:38:09.087  INFO 10028 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-24 23:38:09.187  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@53707808: startup date [Fri Nov 24 23:38:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-24 23:38:09.203  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/welcome]}" onto public java.lang.String com.javainuse.controllers.TestController.firstPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
2017-11-24 23:38:09.207  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-11-24 23:38:09.208  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-11-24 23:38:09.218  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-24 23:38:09.218  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-24 23:38:09.236  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-11-24 23:38:09.307  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-11-24 23:38:09.363  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-11-24 23:38:09.378  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8086 (http)
2017-11-24 23:38:09.381  INFO 10028 --- [  restartedMain] c.j.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication      : Started SpringBootHelloWorldApplication in 1.146 seconds (JVM running for 63.677)
2017-11-24 23:38:23.373  INFO 10028 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-11-24 23:38:23.374  INFO 10028 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-11-24 23:38:23.377  INFO 10028 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 3 ms

```
 > **2017-11-24 23:38:23.386 ERROR 10028 --- [nio-8086-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : **
    > 
    > > [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8086-exec-1] Exception processing template
    > > "welcome": Error resolving template "welcome", template might not
    > > exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template
    > > Resolvers 2017-11-24 23:38:23.388 **ERROR 10028 --- [nio-8086-exec-1]
    > > o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
    > > servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
    > > [Request processing failed; nested exception is
    > > org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
    > > template "welcome", template might not exist or might not be
    > > accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root
    > > cause org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInput**Exception: Error
    > > resolving template "welcome", template might not exist or might not be
    > > accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers  at
    > > org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
    > > ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
    > > org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    > > ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
    > > org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    > > ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
    > > org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    > > ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]**  at
    > > org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    > > ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
    > > org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    > > ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]    at
    > > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
    > > ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    > 
    > **    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    > ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
    > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    > ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
    > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    > ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
    > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    > ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
    > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    > ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
    > javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    > ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
    > javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]     at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    > ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
    > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    > ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    > ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
    > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    > ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    > ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
    > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    > ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    > ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
    > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    > ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    > ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]  at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at
    > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    > [na:1.8.0_121]    at
    > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    > [na:1.8.0_121]    at
    > org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    > [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
    > Source) [na:1.8.0_121]








      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvYoS.png
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `welcome.jsp` this doesn't look like a Thymeleaf template for me. It looks like you are mixing JSP and Thymeleaf.

Comment: Can you provide appconfig class where you specify the view resolver?

Comment: Please give us a reason to help you, and that starts with showing some debugging effort.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy even though i changed my pom.xml by removing <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    
</dependency>  i'm  getting This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Nov 25 01:24:33 IST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available .

Comment: @JigarShah such type of file is not available here directly hitting welcome.jsp page using controller all the configuration has been done in application.properties here is the link available for the same project [link](http://www.javainuse.com/spring/SpringBoot_HelloWorld)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar as i'm new to work on springBoot web application, i'm stuck with this error. please help me out.

Comment: There are millions of resources online for spring boot; do your homework.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar ok

Answer (score 0):

Rename `welcome.jsp` to `welcome.html` and move the file to the directory `src/main/resources/templates/` (create the directory if doesn't exist). By default, thymeleaf templates are read from `src/main/resources/templates` folder.

Comment: My project now started working. i'm no more working with  thymeleaf . i have just cleared my repository and tried to install using maven install in eclipse ... there was some problem with repository folder only... thanks :)